# Нужно ли создавать интерфейсы для DAO классов

Tags: java, hibernate, шаблоны-проектирования, dao

Как вы знаете, в проекте может быть очень много DAO классов, которые в общем случае выполняют одни и те же CRUD операции. Но возникает вопрос, стоит ли для КАЖДОГО дао класса создавать свой интерфейс? Слушая лекцию одного хорошего Java-программиста, он сказал, что не нужно для них создавать интерфейсы, но возможно он имел ввиду, что нужно создавать не для каждого дао свой интерфейс, а только общий (но это не точно). Но вот только дао классы тоже могут иметь разную структуру. Например некоторые могу иметь не все CRUD операции, но мы же не можем их не реализовывать, т.к. реализуем интерфейс, который обязывает нас это делать. 
Или допустим у нас есть интерфейс со стандартными CRUD операциями по типу `findById, update, save` и т.д. А вот в нашем дао классе мы хотим сделать только методы `getMin` и `getMax`. Получается этот интерфейс мы уже не можем использовать. Тогда получается, что нам нужно либо создавать новый интерфейс (а какой шанс, что будет еще один дао класс с таким же функционалом?), либо не создавать интерфейса вообще. Просто представьте, что у нас есть 100 дао классов, нам что, создавать 100 интерфейсов теперь для каждого персонально?

Но с другой стороны программировать дао классы совсем без интерфейсов нельзя. Так вот, что делать в таком случае? Нужно ли для них создавать свои интерфейсы и в каком случае?

Comment: Почитайте про springJPA и Generics. CRUD обычно являются дефолтными операциями. Если нужно что-то другое, это уже ручками пишется. В некоторых случаях слой dao вообще не проектируют. Только entity и service. Что Вам мешает использовать dao с crud для методов getMin и getMax?

Comment: Ответьте для себя на вопрос: - для чего вообще нужны интерфейсы и когда их нужно использовать? Тогда Вам станет понятно стоит ли для каждого DAO создавать интерфейс.

Comment: @Никита если в dao есть только методы getMin и getMax, то там не нужны остальные crud операции, но получается, что мы не можем реализовать интерфейс с дефолтными crud операциями. Поэтому нам нужно либо создать новый интерфейс, либо не создавать его вовсе. Именно в этой ситуации я не знаю, что надо делать. В книге по Hibernate есть пример мини-проекта, и там почти для каждой entity свой dao класс и для каждого из этих dao классов свой личный интерфейс. Но как я уже сказал, некоторые говорят, что интерфейсы дао классам вообще не нужны. Поэтому я меж двух огней и не знаю как правильно поступить